# Running into error "Access to the path 'C:\Users\Work & School\Documents\My Music' is denied." C#-App console

Tags: c#, file, directory, enumeration

i am learning from the tutorial from microsoft "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-enumerate-directories-and-files"

Specifically, this one:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Set a variable to the My Documents path.
            string docPath =
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(docPath, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                        from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                        where line.Contains("Microsoft")
                        select new
                        {
                            File = file,
                            Line = line
                        };

            foreach (var f in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{f.File}\t{f.Line}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{files.Count().ToString()} files found.");
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uAEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(uAEx.Message);
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException pathEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pathEx.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run this file, I run into the error:

Access to the path 'C:\Users\Work & School\Documents\My Music' is denied.

Im wondering, why is it accessing the My Music folder in the first place, when all it should be doing is going to Documents? Furthermore, I also tried deleting the Music folder from a separate folder but i still end up getting the same error. I also put two text files in the document folder, both specifying "Microsoft" so they will return the values from the lines. How would I get rid of the error?

*for the text files, I also turned off the readonly attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why is it accessing the My Music folder in the first place?

> Because of your `SearchOption`. `SeachOption.AllDirectories` searches file in current directory as well as all its subdirectories.

If you want to search only in current directory not in its subdirectories then, change `SearchOption` to `SeachOption.TopDirectoryOnly`

Your updated code should look like,

```
 var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(docPath, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
           from line in File.ReadLines(file)
           where line.Contains("Microsoft")
           select new
           {
                 File = file,
                 Line = line
           };
```

[SearchOption Enum (From MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption?view=netcore-3.1)